# how to disable "this page is tracking your location"

Tags: java, google-chrome, geolocation

I have web app built with java and spring mvc.
When search or category page is opened, for example in google chrome,
popup comes up with a message "Know your location".

How can I disable this feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled this feature by disabling following javascript function:

```
init:function(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function (position){
                ACC.search.coords = position.coords;
            },
            function (error)
            {
                console.log("An error occurred... The error code and message are: " + error.code + "/" + error.message);
            }
        );

    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this feature of Chrome is designed to inform the user about what your web app is doing (possibly against the user's wishes), I would hope and expect that there is no way that your application can disable this.  Indeed, if there was a way, it would largely defeat the purpose<sup>1</sup> of the Chrome notifications.

If you simply want to do this for your own Chrome browser, I suggest that you follow the instructions here:

- https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/stop-showing-desktop-notifications/

If you want to help users of your webapp to disable notifications in their browsers, you could maybe include instructions (for each browser) in your webapp's online documentation.

The best I could find would be to is declare permission (e.g. "geolocation") in the webapp; see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings.  This will (presumably) request the user's consent to grant the permission to the webapp ... once.

Of course, you can stop the notifications by disabling or removing the geolocation tracking feature from your webapp!

---

<sup>1 - Note that this Google developer page on [geolocation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location/) stresses that geolocation should only be done with the user's informed consent.  The idea that you could disable notifications without the user's consent is anathema to that.</sup>